# Regasm BHO from C# Code

Tags: c#, bho, regasm

I have DLL With BHO IE Plugin.

And I use "*regasm.exe /codebase myBHO.dll*" to register my dll.

Is there any C# code to **regasm** my DLL in windows application?

Comment: That's the job of an installer.  A VS Setup project supports it for example.  Do avoid writing your own installer.  But if you insist then you can use RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly().  Note that UAC elevation is required.

Comment: thanks,but I Don't Khow How Can Do this in VS Setup Project, When I Set The "Register" Properties Of my Dll to "vsdraCOM" Not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dedicated installer for this.

For quick debugging cycles from Visual Studio, setup some Build Events like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /f /i $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) 
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) /regfile:$(TargetFileName)64.reg
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /codebase $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /f /i $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) 
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) /regfile:$(TargetFileName)32.reg
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /codebase $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)
```

Then, define a `[ComRegisterFunction]` like:

```
[ComRegisterFunction]
public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
{
    RegistryKey key;
    using (key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects"))
    {
      RegistryKey bhoKey;
      using (bhoKey = key.CreateSubKey(typeName))
      {
        bhoKey.SetValue(string.Empty, "My Awesone IE Plugin");
        bhoKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
      }
    }      
}
```

Comment: This was helpful for me. I had to change the key.CreateSubKey line to be key.CreateSubKey(type.GUID.ToString("B")).