# Window Explorer Error in 64 bit but not 32 bit with BHO

Tags: internet-explorer, 32bit-64bit, gac, bho

For the 64 bit install for the BHO on IE, it seems to interfere with Windows Explorer (claiming System._ComObject cannot find definition for parentWindow). Internet Explorer works just fine with the BHO but I only want it to work on IE.

I've looked around for the last few days trying to find some sort of solution but haven't found anything.

My code looks very similar to the example given in this: [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/how-to-get-started-with-developing-internet-explorer-extensions)

I've changed the code in OnDocumentComplete and added a few methods but I've used the exact same code from the link I included and I still get the error when installing that on 64 bit IE.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question here: [Regasm BHO from C# Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579488/regasm-bho-from-c-sharp-code).

When registering the BHO I needed to include:

```
key.SetValue("NoExplorer,1,RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

I'm unsure as to why it only happened with 64-Bit IE but it works for both now! Hope this helps anyone having issues with it!